# Null pointer while saving the entity in the mongodb through spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am getting the null pointer when i am trying to save the entity in the database .Code for the same is as follows-:

private EligibilityCarrierGroupingRepository eligibilityCarrierGroupingrepository;

```
public String saveEligibilityCarrierGroupingDetails(List<EligibilityCarrierGroupingDoc> eligibilityCarrierGroupinglist) {

    int sizeOfECGlist = eligibilityCarrierGroupinglist.size();
    int i =0;
    System.out.println("Inside the ECG services and the size of the list is "+eligibilityCarrierGroupinglist.size());
    for (EligibilityCarrierGroupingDoc eligibilityCarrierGrouping :eligibilityCarrierGroupinglist) {

        eligibilityCarrierGroupingrepository.save(eligibilityCarrierGrouping);

        i++;

    }
```

and the error i am getting is as follows-:

```
Inside the ECG[EligibilityCarrierGroupingDoc [ecgId=ecg1, carrier=[12345, 456789]], EligibilityCarrierGroupingDoc [ecgId=ecg2, carrier=[ABCDEF, GHIJKL]]]
Inside the ECG services and the size of the list is 2
2018-10-03 07:21:54,519 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR Forwarding to error page from request [/saveEligibilityCarrierGroupingData] due to exception [null]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.prime.eligibility.service.EligibilityCarrierGroupingService.saveEligibilityCarrierGroupingDetails(EligibilityCarrierGroupingService.java:22)
    at com.prime.eligibility.resource.EligibilityCarrierGroupingResource.saveECGData(EligibilityCarrierGroupingResource.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please let me know if anyone came across this kind of exception.

Comment: ho did you inject eligibilityCarrierGroupingrepository object in your service?

Comment: I have defined it as the interface which extends the MongoRepostiory with its doc type ...and have injected it as 
@Autowired
private EligibilityCarrierGroupingRepository eligibilityCarrierGroupingrepository;

Comment: Can you please show your package structure and main class

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have missed wiring the bean.So the eligibilityCarrierGroupingrepository has not been initialized and you are trying to call save method on it.Try putting @autowired annotation on the field eligibilityCarrierGroupingrepository and it should work.

```
@autowired
private EligibilityCarrierGroupingRepository eligibilityCarrierGroupingrepository;
```

Comment: Hi @Shayeeb i have mentioned the Autowired on this.